# How do I upgrade to nginx 1.2.0?

Tags: nginx

Running Ubuntu 11.04 with nginx 0.8.4 how do I upgrade to stable (1.2.0) without screwing my whole setup (multiple sites + varnish + php-fpm + memcache)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I searched a little & found out that the natty version is **0.8.4** and cannot be updated to **1.2.0** by Robert Arkenin's command
To upgrade you should consider adding the ppa by the following commands

```
sudo -s  
nginx=stable # use nginx=development for latest development version  
add-apt-repository ppa:nginx/$nginx  
apt-get update   
apt-get install nginx
```

If you get an error about add-apt-repository not existing, you can try this

```
sudo -s    
nginx=stable # use nginx=development for latest development version  
echo "deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/nginx/$nginx/ubuntu natty main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nginx-$nginx-lucid.list  
apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys C300EE8C  
apt-get update   
apt-get install nginx
```

**Note** The 3rd and 4th line is one command only
For more details refer [Nignx wiki](http://wiki.nginx.org/Install#Ubuntu_PPA)

---

If you are getting this error

> W: Failed to fetch ppa.launchpad.net/nginx//ubuntu/dists/lucid/main/binary-i386/… 404 Not Found E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead

Do this
`sudo nano '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/nginx-stable-lucid.list'`
And then change the contents of the file to
`deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/nginx/stable/ubuntu natty main`

---

#### Something to learn

Actually if you see in the error this part "ppa.launchpad.net/**nginx//ubuntu**/dists/"  should actually be "ppa.launchpad.net/**nginx/stable/ubuntu**/dists/" . that is the error
and sorry for making you add the lucid ppa the first tme.

Comment: Thanks for the help. but I am getting this error: W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/nginx//ubuntu/dists/lucid/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

Comment: @Ashu Got it; sorry for bad information--I'll be more careful next time

Comment: @bran did you use the first method or second

Comment: @bran edited my answer... corrected errors.

Comment: @Ashu still getting the same error. Even after following your updated instructions. Says "nginx is already the newest version.". nginx -v says 0.8.4

Comment: U r welcome... (Though i didnt do much :P)

Answer (score 1):

here's a guide to upgrading / installing to the latest stable or latest development version of nginx without having to compile from sources: http://usefulmix.com/install-upgrade-to-latest-nginx-without-compiling-from-source/

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 1):

```
$sudo apt-key add nginx_signing.key # content of key file is in the guide link
```

Add official nginx source to the sources list by appending the following to the end of /etc/apt/sources.list

```
deb http://nginx.org/packages/ubuntu/ codename nginx  #codename is lucid in ubuntu 10.10 
deb-src http://nginx.org/packages/ubuntu/ codename nginx
```

Then run the following commands:

```
$sudo apt-get update
$sudo install nginx
```

I update the nginx from 0.7 to 1.7 in ubuntu 10.10 by following [the guide](http://nginx.org/en/linux_packages.html#stable). Hope this will help others.

Comment: Link only answers are usually not wanted. It's better to summarize the content of the link in your answer. So it's easier to see what the link is about and your answer doesn't become worthless in case the link breaks.

Comment: @Minos Thanks for your kindly suggestion. Now i have added a brief summary.